# getServerSession() return { user: { name: undefined, email: undefined, image: undefined } }

Tags: typescript, server-side, next-auth, next.js13

I have a server side component this file is *.jsx and I need have user logged id for an http request, but when I run this line `const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);` session catch { user: { name: undefined, email: undefined, image: undefined } }

I am using

- next-auth: "^4.22.0"
- next": 13.2

this is my [...nextauth].ts file

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import api from "../../../settings";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/login",
        // error: "/auth/error",
        // signOut: "auth/logout"
    },
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            type: 'credentials',
            name: 'Ingresar',
            credentials: {},
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const { email, password } = credentials as {
                    email: string,
                    password: string
                };

                const res = await fetch(`${api}/login`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({email, password})
                })
                const user = await res.json()
    
                // If no error and we have user data, return it
                if (res.ok && user) {
                    console.log(user)
                    return user
                }
                // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
                return null
            }
        })
    ]
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Comment: Could you rephrase this? It's not clear what your actual problem is. Is this related to TS types or are you getting a runtime error?